# How does wordpress restrict X-FRAME to sameorigin?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have two wordpress sites I'll call one sourceURL and the one  destinationURL.  destinationURL has an iframe to present content from the sourceURL.  When I attempt to run the iframe presenting the content from the other I get the following error:

```
destinationURL refused to display sourceURL in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

I can't seem to find where the x-frame option is being set by wordpress.  I checked the following:

- .htaccess - I removed any security options I had in the htaccess file.  I also tried to enable x-frame via the htaccess.  Doing this gives me an error that I have two conflicting rules.

  `<IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM destinationURL“
  </IfModule>`
- all root wp- related files.  I can't seem to find any config updating the setting.
- plugins - I removed security plugins in case they were setting my option to sameorigin, and I tried plugins that are meant to update the x-frame option.

At this stage, I suspect wordpress has a default configuration.

How does wordpress restrict x-frame options to sameorigin?

I was hoping one of you experienced this before and walk me through how wordpress disables x-frame options before I grep for 'x-frame' or sameorigin across all the files.

**--Update--**

I created a wordpress plugin to remove their security as the variable.  I realized afterwards that the X-Frame Error I was receiving was lowercase (sameorigin), which highlighted that it wasn't coming from wordpress as their files all are set to uppercase.

I spoke to my web hosting provider and discovered they set their apache config to restrict X-Frames.

To correct my issue, I added the following line to my .htaccess file.  Hope this helps someone.

```
Header always unset X-Frame-Options
```

Comment: It took less time to grep across the files (via Github) than it probably took to type your question out, FYI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=x-frame-options

The [`send_frame_options_header`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2f3e91028aa470139120380c3bae713482eeb06d/wp-includes/functions.php#L5067) function handles this. It's an action tied to the `login_init` hook.

You can remove it by doing this in a custom plugin:

```
remove_action('login_init', 'send_frame_options_header');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This didn't correct my specific issue, but was the answer to my question it helped remove wordpress as the variable.